# Function to delete rows taking the PK as the parameter

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I want to create a function with no return value to delete a record in a table named bill based on the primary key bill_key. The column is called bill_key. The code I have is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.delete_bill(bill_key_to_delete bigint)
RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
begin
  DELETE FROM bill
  WHERE "bill_key" = bill_key_to_delete;
  return;
end;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
```

I call the function:

```
select delete_bill(2);
```

But the error message I get is:

```
select delete_bill(2)
        ERROR:  column reference "bill_key" is ambiguous
        LINE 2: WHERE "bill_key" = bill_key_to_delete
                      ^
        DETAIL:  It could refer to either a PL/pgSQL variable or a table column.
        QUERY:  DELETE FROM bill
        WHERE "bill_key" = bill_key_to_delete
        CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function delete_bill(bigint) line 2 at SQL statement
```

Comment: What happens if you use a qualified column name (including the table alias)?

Comment: The error message suggest that you are not showing us the complete source of your function

Answer (score 0):

Try with alias for table name:

```
DELETE FROM bill b
WHERE b."bill_key" = bill_key_to_delete;
```

and if function return void type you should use `PERFORM` to execute function

```
PERFORM delete_bill(2);
```

Comment: `perform` is only available inside a PL/pgSQL function. You can't use that through "plain" SQL